# VSTS push docker-compose to Azure Container Registry and WebApp

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, azure-devops

I would like to configure continuous integration from VSTS to Azure Container Registry and then to WebApp.

Here's my ***docker-compose.yml*** file:
As you can see I'm using an Asp.Net core + mssql. 
    version: '3'

```
services:
  api:
    image: tbacr.azurecr.io/myservice/api
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "testtest3030!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:1433"
```

Here's my task from VSTS:
[image]

And I think the major task is ***Build Services*** and ***PublishServices***
So, please take a look below:
**Build Services**
[image]

***PublishServices***
[image]

And finally, in Azure Container Registry I have:
[image]

So, the question is how can I deploy it to the WebApp. I have tried right-click to api: latest repository and deploy to WebApp but the endpoint does not respond

Comment: +1 because I was trying to figure out my build with docker-compose, rather than a build step for each (currently 5) services, and some of your settings from your screen shots helped, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 steps im VSTS : build and release. It seems your build part is ok. So your docker image is pushed in your repo. Then you have to configure the build part in VSTS that will get the image you just pushed on the repo and deploy it on a server.

HTH

Comment: but as you can see I have only one image in my Azure Registry Container (for api). What about image for mssql ?

Comment: Your docker image for the DB is the official one, so it is public. I suppose your target server has docker, so it will be able to dowload it.

Comment: @Fiver Optic Okay, I see, but when I deploy tag 91 to web app for container and try to open the uri in the browser I get HTTP 503, Do you know what I am doing wrong?